# Ansible synchronize does not copy files

Tags: ansible, yaml, ansible-2.x

I'm trying to test `synchronize` module in order to copy the content from a local directory  on remote host.

However seems that synch does not copy the files present from local directory.

My environment is composed by two VM (controller and target) with centos 7, running on virtual box.

This is my test.yaml playbook:

```
- hosts: publisher
  name: 'Test sync'
  gather_facts: false
  become: true
  become_user: osboxes
  become_method: su
  tasks:
    - name: sync
      synchronize:
        src: /home/osboxes/ansible/roles/deploy/files/application
        dest: /opt/application
        recursive: no
      delegate_to: localhost
```

The content of the publisher directory is the following:

```
total 17220
drwxrwxr-x. 3 osboxes osboxes       83 Jun 14 07:10 .
drwxrwxr-x. 4 osboxes osboxes       40 Jun 14 04:33 ..
-rw-rw-r--. 1 osboxes osboxes       30 Jun 14 03:22 application.yml
drwxr-xr-x. 3 osboxes osboxes    12288 Jun 14 07:10 html
-rw-rw-r--. 1 osboxes osboxes      222 Jun 14 01:34 application.env
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 osboxes osboxes 17608703 Jun 14 01:34 application.jar
```

Finally this is my inventory file:

```
target ansible_host=10.0.2.7 ansible_connection=ssh ansible_user=osboxes ansible_ssh_pass='asdasd' ansible_become_password=asdasd 
localhost ansible_host=127.0.0.1 ansible_connection=ssh ansible_user=osboxes ansible_ssh_pass='osboxes.org' ansible_become_password='osboxes.org' 

[publisher]
target
```

By running this playbook I obtain:

```
$ ansible-playbook test.yaml -i inventory.txt --diff 

PLAY [Test sync] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [sync] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [target -> localhost]

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
target                    : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

But in the remote host dir no files are being copied:

```
$ ansible target -m shell -a "ls -al /opt/*" -i inventory.txt 
target2 | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
/opt/application:
total 0
drwxrwxr-x. 2 osboxes osboxes  6 Jun 15 19:42 .
drwxr-xr-x. 4 osboxes root    33 Jun 15 19:42 ..

/opt/rh:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root    root  6 Oct 30  2018 .
drwxr-xr-x. 4 osboxes root 33 Jun 15 19:42 ..
```

From ansible doc, the expected result in the remote host should be that all application* files are copied into remote path `/opt/application` except the html dir:

```
total 17220
drwxrwxr-x. 3 osboxes osboxes       83 Jun 14 07:10 .
drwxrwxr-x. 4 osboxes osboxes       40 Jun 14 04:33 ..
-rw-rw-r--. 1 osboxes osboxes       30 Jun 14 03:22 application.yml
-rw-rw-r--. 1 osboxes osboxes      222 Jun 14 01:34 application.env
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 osboxes osboxes 17608703 Jun 14 01:34 application.jar
```

At the moment the only way I have found to make the sync work is to add the `dirs: yes` option in the playbook, but that also copy the html folder (I also tried `recursive: no` but still copy the html folder without the internal content).

Thanks in advance for any replies.

**Update #1**

I tried the rsync_opts with `"-f'- */'"` & `"-f'+ *'"` as @Zeitounator suggested but receive syntax error:

```
$ ansible-playbook test.yaml -i inventory.txt -vvvvv
[omitted output]
TASK [sync] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [target2]: FAILED! => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
    }, 
    "changed": false, 
    "cmd": "sshpass -d8 /usr/bin/rsync --delay-updates -F --compress --archive --rsh=/usr/bin/ssh -S none -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -f'- */' -f'+ *' --out-format=<<CHANGED>>%i %n%L /home/osboxes/ansible/roles/deploy/files/application/ osboxes@10.0.2.7:/opt/application/", 
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "_local_rsync_password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER", 
            "_local_rsync_path": "rsync", 
            "_substitute_controller": false, 
            "archive": true, 
            "checksum": false, 
            "compress": true, 
            "copy_links": false, 
            "delete": false, 
            "dest": "osboxes@10.0.2.7:/opt/application/", 
            "dest_port": null, 
            "dirs": false, 
            "existing_only": false, 
            "group": null, 
            "link_dest": null, 
            "links": null, 
            "mode": "push", 
            "owner": null, 
            "partial": false, 
            "perms": null, 
            "private_key": null, 
            "recursive": null, 
            "rsync_opts": [
                "-f'- */'", 
                "-f'+ *'"
            ], 
            "rsync_path": null, 
            "rsync_timeout": 0, 
            "set_remote_user": true, 
            "src": "/home/osboxes/ansible/roles/deploy/files/application/", 
            "ssh_args": null, 
            "times": null, 
            "verify_host": false
        }
    }, 
    "msg": "Unknown filter rule: `'- */''\nrsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at exclude.c(927) [client=3.1.2]\n", 
    "rc": 1
}
```

However, running the rsync command directly with opts works:

```
$ rsync -a -f'- */' -f'+ *' /home/osboxes/ansible/roles/deploy/files/application/ osboxes@10.0.2.7:/opt/application/
```

Comment: You are delegating the task to localhost, so the controller synchs the files to... itself. Remove `delegate_to: localhost` and you should be good.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Unfortunately by removing `delegate_to: localhost` the files are not copied anyway. I found another workaround that consist of adding `rsync_opts:"--exclude=html"` and it works in conjunction with  `delegate_to: localhost`. However it is weird because I agree with you that `delegate_to: localhost` needs to be removed

Comment: `I prefer to use this module instead of the copy module to get better performance for large file transfer.` <= The gain you will get from using `synchronize` will be much more perceptible for **numerous** files rather than for **large** files

Comment: @Zeitounator you are right, I delete this sentence because is misleading

Answer (score 1):

Adapted form [this other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/632102/735216)

```yaml
    - name: sync
      synchronize:
        src: /home/osboxes/ansible/roles/deploy/files/application/
        dest: /opt/application/
        archive: true
        rsync_opts:
          - "-f'- */'"
          - "-f'+ *'"
```

This basically make rsync push the `src` directory content taking into account all files and removing directories. Note that trailing slashes in `src` and `dest` are important.

Comment: I receive the following error: `fatal: [target2]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "sshpass -d8 /usr/bin/rsync --delay-updates -F --compress --archive --no-group --rsh=/usr/bin/ssh -S none -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -f\"- */\" -f\"+ *\" --out-format=<<CHANGED>>%i %n%L /home/osboxes/ansible/roles/deploy/files/applcation/ osboxes@10.0.2.7:/opt/application/", "msg": "Unknown filter rule: '\"- */\"'\nrsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at exclude.c(927) [client=3.1.2]\n", "rc": 1}`

Comment: However starting from your suggestion I tried `rsync_opts` with `"--exclude=*/"` and it works as expected, so all the file are copied except the html dir. So this could be the clean solution I guess.

Comment: The only way I can reproduce the error in your comment is by deliberately removing the single quotes inside the options which are part of my example.

Comment: I copied and paste your snipped and tried with single quote and double quote (by inverting them) and all attempts fail with the same error. I added an update to the post by adding the complete error message. I miss something?